# Problem with postgres passing parameters in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have this code which take title, or isbn, or an author of a book and retrieve all matching data from database.

The problem is with the passing parameter line, it retrieve only the first record, regardling of the data that the user enter.

I tried to use the **select statement** it in the data base console and it retrieve the correct statement, which i understand that **the cur.execute that pass the parameters line is not right.**  Can you help me with this and thanks in advance.

This is the code

```
class Searchb:
    def __init__(self,isbn,author,title):
        self.isbn=isbn
        self.author=author
        self.title=title

    def booksearch(self):
        query= "select author,title from books where isbn LIKE '%%s%%' OR author LIKE '%%s%%' OR title like '%%s%%' "
        cur.execute(query,(self.isbn,self.author,self.title),)
        book=cur.fetchmany()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the select statement and I could find myself the correct syntax of select statement with Like at the same time you pass parameters to database; postgres

```
query="select author,title from books where isbn LIKE %s or author like %s or title like %s "
              book_to_search=(self.isbn,self.author,self.title)
              cur.execute(query,book_to_search)
              book=cur.fetchall()
```

THANKS FOR EVERYONE!

Answer (score 0):

You are using cur.fetchmany() without any paramters.  From [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html):

> The number of rows to fetch per call is specified by the parameter. If it is not given, the cursor’s arraysize determines the number of rows to be fetched.

arraysize defaults to 1, which is why you are only getting 1 row.  Either specify something higher iterate until you get no more results or just use `cur.fetchall()`

Comment: No i tried to use fetchall() the same results. The results was not correct.

Comment: You said that it retrieved only the first record.  What was not correct about the results?

Comment: Retrieve the first record in the database or retrieve all, whatever isbn or author name or title book you asked for??